# Passing variable from render array in Controller to javascript in twig

Tags: javascript, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I want to pass $reservationData to the twig template so I can use it in javascript.

Here is my Controller:

```
class MovieReservation extends ControllerBase{
  public function page(){
    return [
      '#reservation' => $reservationData,
    ];
  }
```

I need it in javascript functions so I can populate it with the informations I want.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass data into **drupalSettings** object :

```
  class MovieReservation extends ControllerBase {
    public function page() {
      return [
        '#reservation' => $reservationData, // It's for twig template.
        '#attached' => [
           'drupalSettings' => [
             'reservation' => $reservationData, // It's for javascript file.
           ],
        ],
      ];
    }
```

And into your javascript file:

```
drupalSettings.reservation
```

Note : You can add javascript file via libraries.yml file

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I have a script inside twig, so I think I can use it that way :) Does that mean that I have to insert attached into hook theme? :)

Comment: @MajaB No needs to declare #attached into theme hook it's a native property into drupal. So, it's not a good thing to have javascript into twig file , you must put javascript into external file attached to rendering process https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module

Comment: Ok! :) Thanks for the answer!